# Another stacking centered images question

Tags: image, layer, stacked

I have an image of TV set and I want to place images of "shows" in it, centered horizontally on the screen (in front of the tv screen image). I'm using a  to set the dimensions of the area in which to place the images, but I don't have to if it's not necessary. I've fiddled with position:absolute/relative of the  and the images, but I can't get both images to be centered and stacked - either they partly overlap when centered or they align perfectly at the edge of the "". Here's the current iteration of the code. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
<div id="sourceDiv" align="center">
    <img class="test" src="uvaCover.jpg" style="z-index:2; width:800px">
    <img class="test" src = "tvScreen.jpg" style="z-index:1; width:900px">
</div>

.test {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

#sourceDiv {
  position:relative;
  background-color: red;
  top:170px;
  left: 20px;
  width:1000px;
  height: 800px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. For the ":

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```